# React-native typescript template not compiling tsc, tsx fles

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I have created a new expo app with a blank (TypeScript) template, and create a script entry in a package JSON file like this.

```
"compile-project":"tsc --watch"
```

but the project not compiling the any of tsc, tsx files in my project directory while running the "compile-project" command.

here is my tsconfg file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "strict": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're setting up to stop emit files by giving `noEmit: true`. This option is only useful for checking the typing only.

Try to switch it back to `false` to see the compiled files in the output:

`tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "noEmit": false,
  } 
}
```